# Compile .less file in Visual Studio without web essentials?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, less

I know Web Essentials can compile less files. Are there any other VS plugins that can compile .less files?

VS 2013 update 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Compiling has in fact been taken out of Web Essentials 2015, using gulp and grunt is now the preferred approach.  To compile LESS with Grunt you can use [grunt-contrib-less](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less).

To get your Grunt or Gulp file to run nicely in Visual Studio you can use [Task Runner Explorer Extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8e1b4368-4afb-467a-bc13-9650572db708).  Scott Hanselman has a good [post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingGulpGruntBowerAndNpmSupportForVisualStudio.aspx) introducing this.

I have written a post showing you how to [compile SASS using the Task Runner Explorer](http://www.iambacon.co.uk/blog/getting-started-with-grunt-sass-and-task-runner-explorer-visual-studio).  This approach can also be transferred to LESS of course.

This [article](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/grunt-and-bower-in-visual-studio-2015) shows you how to compile with Grunt and LESS also.

Comment: I marked this as the answer, but ended up going with Koala for simplicity.